# Javascript and Jquery Retrieving and Updating HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having trouble editing information. i put comments in the code to show where i am having trouble.

```
//Load edit client form to container
    $("#editClient").click(function (){
        $("#container").load("html/search_client.html #target");
        $("#container").css({"display" : "block"});
        $(".form").css({ "width" : "200px", "margin" : "0 Auto" });

        $("#target").ready(function () {
            $(".choose").hover(function() {
            $(this).css({"background-color":"blue", "box-shadow": "-2px 2px 4px black"});
            },function(){
            $(this).css({"background-color" : "navy", "box-shadow": "-4px 4px 8px black"});
            });


            $("#search").click(function(){
                var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

                ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function (){
                    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
                        var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('data');
                        ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
                    }
                };

                var fName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
                var lName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
                var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
                var clientID = document.getElementById('client-id').value;
                var queryStr = "?firstName=" + fName + "&lastName=" + lName + "&address=" + address + "&client-id="+ clientID;

                ajaxRequest.open("GET", "php/edit_client.php" + queryStr, true);
                ajaxRequest.send(null);

                //everything works fine until i get here

                $("#client-info").ready(function(){
                    var tableRows = document.getElementById('target').getElementsByClassName('row');
                    rowsLength = tableRows.length;
                    alert("you have " + rowsLength +" rows"); //this alerts 0 on the first click then alerts 1 on all clicks after
                    i = 0;
                    while(i < rowsLength){
                    $("button.editFirstName").click(function(){ //this click function just wont work
                        var oldFirstName = document.getElementById('container').getElementById(i).getElementsByClassName('first-name').value;
                        $(".first-name").html("<input type = 'text' name = 'first-name'><br><button id = 'confirm'>Confirm</button><button id = 'Deny'>Deny</button>");


                        $("#confirm").click(function(){
                            ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

                            ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
                                if (ajaxRequest.readyState === 4){
                                    ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById(i).getElementByClassName("first-name");
                                    ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
                                }
                            };

                            var editClientID = document.getElementById(i).getElementByClassName("client-id").value;
                            var editFirstName = document.getElementById(i).getElementByName("first-name").value;
                            queryStr = "?editType=fname&editID=" + editClientID + "&editValue=" + editFirstName;

                            ajaxRequest.open("GET", "php/confirm_edit.php");
                            ajaxRequest.send(null);
                        });

                        $("#deny").click(function(){

                        });
                    });
                    i++;
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

i'm not sure what is going on i've tried so many things and can't find out why my rowsLength wont calculate right on the first attempt and why the button.editFirstName click function wont work.

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery and old school javascript?

Comment: I suspect your problem involves the calls to `.getElementById(i)`. `i` is a number which, by itself, isn't a valid id. Even if it did work, do you really have elements that read like `<div id="0">`?

Comment: yes i do they auto increase with multiple clients. how could i make it work then?

Comment: @Ouroborus numbers are not invalid ID's in html5

Comment: Structurally you have numerous nested event listeners inside other event handlers. This is a bad practice especially with multiple nesting levels. Logic is probably incorrect

Comment: @charlietfl My bad. The looser restrictions are new to HTML5. Prior to that, id couldn't start with a digit.

Comment: @Ouroborus right, but was never really a problem and would work cross browser